# Not able to load image file from URL using javascript, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i make a request to load image using javascipt like.

```
<div class="col col-20">
       <img ng-src="{{img}}">
</div>
```

the network tabs show error like:

```
Please enable cookies.
Error 1011 Ray ID: xxxxxx • 2016-11-14 19:02:05 UTC

Access denied

What happened?

The owner of this website (xxx) does not allow hotlinking to that resource (xxx/file.jpg).
```

but if i open the image url in browser by copy and pasting in url bar the image loads...

and now to surprise the image starts getting loaded in application also.

but, only the image i have opened in browser separately loads correctly or other the same error is received.

Comment: When you don't understand the problem or don't just know the answer.. don't down-vote the questions.

Comment: Try not to make assumptions about *why* people downvote a question.

Comment: @Quentin but, it doesn't make any sense.. when someone down-votes without any reason. At least one should comment. I don't think there is anything wrong in this question.

Comment: There is no requirement for people to explain downvotes. At least three people think there is something wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i open the image url in browser by copy and pasting in url bar the image loads.

That is expected. Look at the error message:

> The owner of this website (xxx) does not allow hotlinking

Opening directly is not hotlinking.

Hotlinking is when you load an image from another website and try to use their bandwidth to put their image on your site. This could cost them money (because bandwidth from hosting services isn't free) and it could violate copyright.

You're trying to be a freeloader and they are taking steps to prevent you.

> now to surprise the image starts getting loaded in application also

The browser cached the image after you opened it directly, so you are now loading it from the local browser cache isn't of the website that forbids hotlinking.

Comment: (1) Make sure you have permission from the copyright holder to use the image (or that the image is in the public domain) then (2) Host the image on your own hosting.

Comment: yes.. apart from the above two .. some technical stuff..like by transforming the `GET` request.. as it can be fetched by browser.. so its also possible to fetch from request in javascript ?? Isn't it ?

Comment: No. The Same Origin Policy would block access from JS entirely. Stop trying to freeload.

Comment: @Quentin is right, this is a policy from that site to prevent people using their sites as file server of someone else. It's like I were using your machine to run a Tibia server just because you have let a port opened. By blocking this they are closing that port avoiding you to use theirs machine's resources. So the best approach is to avoid a freeloading, and ask for an authorization or store the image on your server as Quentin have told before. Cheers :{D

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro  i know, and this is fair. Lets think about technical perspective.. When browser can directly load the resource then we can also load that by request from js..  I mean their may be a difference of some headers only in both requests.. rights ?

Comment: @atulquest93 — The technical perspective is: **The browser will block you from reading the data with JS**. Even if that wasn't the case, the standard for XHR forbids you from manipulating the referer header (which is the one that anti-hotlinking code watches). There are lots of things that a user of a browser can make their browser do that the author of some JavaScript can't make a browser that visits their website do. There would be massive security problems otherwise.

Comment: But, the request is not a `XHR` its a `GET` request. Their are many restrictions with `XHR` but not as such for 'GET'.  What you think ? @Quentin

Comment: @atulquest93 — XHR is not an HTTP request method, it is the API you use to make any kind of HTTP request (including GET requests) with JavaScript.

Comment: Found a workaround.. i hit a php file on server which in turn curls the image from server. Adding `referrer` header in php with request solves the problem.

Comment: @atulquest93 — Congratulations. You have skipped step 1 of my advice (making sure you aren't violating copyright) and gone on to step 2 (host it yourself) except you aren't keeping the image and are (slowly) fetching it from the third party *every time* you want to share it. That's the worst of both worlds.